# Default Python paths when using VSCode interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Suppose the Python package `mypackage` is at a non-standard location on my machine and I am running Python code in the VSCode interactive window. If I type

`import mypackage`

it will not be found. This can be remedied by doing `sys.path.append("/path/to/mypackage")`. However, I would like to set things up so that within a given project each time I open the interactive window a set of paths, like `/path/to/mypackage`, have already been added to the search path. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to modify the `PYTHONPATH`:

1. Add these in the settings.json file to Modify the `PYTHONPATH` in the terminal:

   **"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
   "PYTHONPATH": "xxx/site-packages"
   }**
2. Create a `.env` file under your workspace, and add these settings in it to modify the `PYTHONPATH` for the extension and debugger:

   **PYTHONPATH=xxx/site-packages**

You can refer to [here][1] to understand the effects of these two configurations.